# ***Android NDK : Aborting. Stop

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am getting following error after importing my existing project in eclipse.

> > *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
> >         external location: G:\Android_Setup\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9d\build\core\add-application.mk   C/C++ Problem.

**File System**
 http://i57.tinypic.com/2ps3p88.png

```
 G:\AdroidApp\Meddiff --> Android codebase
```

Andriod.mk has

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := Meddiff

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Meddiff.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Environment Variables**

My Machine is 64 bit(windows 8.1)

```
 APP_PROJECT_PATH = G:\AdroidApp\Meddiff
 NDK_PROJECT_PATH = G:\Android_Setup\android-ndk-r9d-windows-x86\android-ndk-r9d
```

Comment: Why don't you read the ndk tutorial from android developer's site ? You have to setup envirronement variable in eclipse, including the ndk location on disk. Did you made it ?

Comment: Is your `$PATH` correctly setup, i mean, compiler command line tools are available ?

Comment: Another guess : what seems to be said in your error, is that the location G: ... is external which is not accepted. Try run everything on the same physical hard drive

Comment: You would describe better how you have configured your computer. Your post doesn't help to response your question.

Comment: You'd probably get a much more informative error if you invoked ndk-build from the command line, though I'll grant that windows command terminal boxes are horrid (ultimately you might find switching your android work to linux or OSX will save lots of effort and frustration)

Comment: Thanks for your comments i have skipped this issue and facing some other issue that i have posted as a new question please help me to solve